# Can I compare with more than one string in an if statement?

Tags: c++

This is gonna be laughed at because I'm probably very stupid, but can I use more than one string as a condition in an if statement?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Baxter.h"
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "Room1Items.h"


int woman = 6;
int children = 5;

int inputNumberOfAnimalsToSave;
int numberOfAnimals;
int numberOfAnimalsToKill;
int numberOfAnimalToTakeHome;
std::string Yes;
std::string firstAction;

bool killRemainingAnimals;
int playerSaidYes;

int AddNumber()
{
    numberOfAnimals = woman + children;
    return numberOfAnimals;
}

int RemoveNumber() 
{
    numberOfAnimalsToKill = numberOfAnimalToTakeHome - numberOfAnimals;

    return numberOfAnimalsToKill;
}

int InputNumber() 
{

    std::cout << "   Comrade Kurchenko:  Well, they are irridiated and will most likely end up poisioning \n";
    std::cout << "     your family, but sure, why not! How many animals Shall we Save ?\n ";
    std::cin >> inputNumberOfAnimalsToSave;
    numberOfAnimalToTakeHome = numberOfAnimals - inputNumberOfAnimalsToSave;

    return numberOfAnimalToTakeHome;
}
int DoYouWantToKillTheRest() 
{

        std::cout << "   Comrade Kurchenko:   Fair Enough Comrade! Do you want to move on? \n\n";
        std::cout << "   Private Lenin:  "; std::cin >> Yes;

    while (Yes == "No") 
    {

            //std::cout << "   Comrade Kurchenko:  So, you want the remaining " << numberOfAnimalToTakeHome << " Put The sleep do you?\n\n";
            //std::cout << "   Private Lenin:  Im afraid so sir!\n\n";

            //std::cout << "   Comrade Kurchenko:  Then so be it. They will be better off dead by our hands, than starving to death.\n\n\n\n";
            //std::cout << "       *** Loud Bangs and Then Silence....\n\n\n ***";


        std::cout << "   Comrade Kurchenko:  What do you want to do?\n";
        std::cout << "   Private Lenin:  "; std::cin >> firstAction; std::cout << "\n";

        while (firstAction != "MoveOn")
        {



            if (firstAction == "Take food" || "Recover Meal" )
            {
                if (canTakeFood) 
                {
                    TakeFood();
                    std::cout << "    You have taken a peice of food \n";
                    DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
                }
                if (canTakeFood == false) 
                {
                    std::cout << "   There is no more food to take \n";
                    DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
                }

            }

            if (firstAction == "Eatfood")
            {
                EatFood();
                DoYouWantToKillTheRest();

            }

            if (firstAction == "Inventory")
            {
                ShowInventory();
                DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
            }

            if (firstAction == "Ouch") 
            {
                JabAFingerInYourEye();
                std::cout << "   Comrade Kurchenko : Why the hell did you stab yourself in the eye?\n\n";
                std::cout << "   Private Lenin : I dont know sir, its like someone was controlling my arm!\n";

                DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
            }

            if (firstAction == "Look")
            {
                Look();
                DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
            }

            if( firstAction == "Help")
            {
                WhatCanIDo();
                DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
            }
            if (firstAction == "Baxter")
            {
                ShowBaxter();
                std::cout << "Here is baxter";
                DoYouWantToKillTheRest();
            }

        }
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried it and get no bugs when I run it. It just doesn't work.
I have tried to google it but I can't seem to find the right way to word it to get results. Messing around with a console based text adventure.

I've googled as many different ways of asking this question and can't get any results that help me.

I get no error messages. It runs fine, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Is firstAction  a c-style string (char* ) or a std::string? If it is a string literal you have to use, for example strcmp(firstAction, "Take food") == 0 . As Slava says, please, post a minimum reproducible example so we can help you.

Comment: @Slava Just curious, how to create an mvce on stackoverflow for `c++`?

Comment: Yes with ``&&`` operator

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava you provide source code that  can be copy-pasted to a file and compiled as it is and reproduce the problem.

Comment: like the comments above, you should probably do something like `if(firstAction.compare("Take Food") == 0)` in stead of the literal string comparison. I believe the literal string comparison will check if memory addresses are the same, but I could be wrong. You can see how to use str.compare [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparing-two-strings-cpp/).

Also where are you trying to use more than 1 string in an if statement. I would debug this by doing `cout << firstAction <<endl;` at the start of the loop. This would show if the loop executes or not, and what the value of firstAction is.

Comment: What was the expected result? What this loop was supposed to achieve?

Comment: Back to the original issue: this question doesn't contain enough information to give a decent answer. The types ain't specified and the intention of comparing 2 strings ain't clear.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava You create the MCVE on your local machine or with an online compiler. Then copy and paste the code here.

Answer (score 4):

"Can I compare with more than one string in an if statement?" - Sure you can (I'm assuming we are talking about `std::string`s here).

You are doing

```
if (firstAction == "Take food")
```

If you wanted to test against two strings you *could* do:

```
if (firstAction == "Take food" or firstAction == "Drop food")
```

You could change that `or` to `||` which is more conventional, but both are valid and do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ (and most other programming languages) you usually can't compare one thing (a string variable) to multiple others in one operation because of the way operator precedence is defined:

```
// Does not work!!
if (firstAction == "Take food" || "Recover Meal" )
// Because it will evaluate to (firstAction == "Take food") || "Recover Meal"
```

Rather you use logical operators to combine the result of one comparison with another comparison:

```
if (firstAction == "Take food" || firstAction == "Recover Meal")
{
```

You should read up on logical operators in C++ to learn more, for instance here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/36-logical-operators/

If you want to dynamically compare to a whole list of strings, then you can do so of course as well:

```
std::set<std::string> validActions = {"Take food", "Recover meal"};
if (validActions.find(firstAction) != validActions.end())
{
  // ... found a valid action ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you compare c-strings in C++. That type of string is just an array of characters and operator `==` tells if it is the same array, not if it has the same content.
To compare strings properly use function [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) from `<cstring>`.

```
firstAction == "Take food"; // bad
strcmp(firstAction, "Take food") == 0; // good
```

Better yet solution would be using class [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) which allows to use normal operators.

```
std::string(firstAction) == "Take food"; // good
std::string(firstAction) == std::string("Take food"); // also good
firstAction == std::string("Take food"); // also good
```

Or, like @JVApen has hinted, maybe even better solution would be to use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view).

```
firstAction == std::string_view("Take food"); // good
firstAction == "Take food"sv; // the same meaning as above but written shorter
```

You just need to remember to insert line `using std::operator""sv;` before that. (`using namespace std;` would also do.)

---

If you comparing string properly (let's say using the `std::string_view`) then of course you can use `||` (or) or `&&` (and) or any other operator to make multiple comparisons in a single `if`.

```
if (firstAction == "Take food"sv || firstAction == "Take water"sv)
{
    // do stuff
}
if (firstAction == "Take food"sv && !canTakeFood)
    std::cout << "   There is no more food to take \n";
    LoopAndDoAction();
}
```

(This code probably doesn't make sense but it's just an example.)

---

Depending on what are you trying to do, consider using `enum` instead of string constants. Enums are faster, more readable, take less memory and there is harder to make mistake like a type when using it. Actually, only situation I can think of when you would not want to use enum would be parsing user input.

Comment: I made a typo while writing "typo". It is too ironic to fix it.

Comment: "This is not how you compare c-strings in C++. That type of string is just an array of characters and operator == tells if it is the same array, not if it has the same content. " - That is *not* correct if `firstAction` is a `std::string`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl On the one hand, true. On the other, I can't think of other reason why it wouldn't work so I allowed myself to guess. I'll just hover my mouse over delete button until it become clear.

Comment: I think it's better to write `"Take food"sv` instead, much more intuative code

Comment: @JVApen Well, I've learned something new today. Answer improved.

Answer (score -1):

The second if is with who you can compare strings a lot of strings if you find some condition true on these if, the entire condition will be true.

I exaplained all on code `//comments`

**Documentation:** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string str1ok = "Im a string";
    string str2ok = "Im a string";
    string str3ok = "Im a string different";
    //First condition with and operator (&&) you can compare with a lot && operators
    if(str1ok.compare(str2ok) == 0 && str3ok.compare(str2ok) == 0){ //First condition is true, second false, this condition is false because have true and false, need have true and true for be true
        cout << "1st condition" << endl;
    }
    //Another condition with or operator (||) one condition need be true, if not is false
    if(str1ok.compare(str2ok) == 0 || str3ok.compare(str2ok) == 0){ //First condition is true, only for this this condition is true, second condition is false.
        cout << "2nd condition" << endl;
    }
    //You can make a mixed the operators like this some condition && (anothercondition || condition)

    return 0;
}
```

**Ouptput:** https://onlinegdb.com/By39WpOGS

Comment: Why do you recommend `std::string::compare` when `std::string` also defines all the [normal comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)?

Comment: Yes, i put this because on old times i has problems with string == string, never compare, idk the reason, i know with .compare function works like a charm!!, yes now works, i see the documentation page what you put, thanks for share info!!